# Label on Chartjs and Vue not displaying

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I am working on a chart that should display a graphic with bars and lines. I want to show the number on the chart, but i can't make it. The console gives me this error:

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ctx').

The graphic should look like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg70Y.png)

But instead i have the graphics without the numbers on the bars and lines.

Anyone knows why this happens? Thanks in advance!

```
<template>
  <div>
    <canvas id="miGrafico"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// Importa Chart.js
import { Chart } from 'chart.js/auto';

export default {

  data() {
      return {

      };
  },

  mounted() {

    const canvasElement = document.getElementById('miGrafico');
    const ctx2 = canvasElement.getContext('2d');

    // Datos de ejemplo para las jornadas
    const jornadas = ['J1', 'J2', 'J3', 'J4', 'J5'];
    const puntuaciones = [10, 15, 8, 20, 12];
    const goles = [1, 0, 2, 1, 3];
    const asistencias = [3, 2, 4, 1, 2];

    new Chart(ctx2, {
      type: 'bar', // Tipo de gráfico de barras
      data: {
        labels: jornadas,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Puntuación',
            data: puntuaciones,
            backgroundColor: '#0493FE', // Color de las barras de puntuación
            barPercentage: 0.3, // Reduce el ancho de las barras de puntuación
            categoryPercentage: 0.8,
            order: -1, // Coloca las barras de puntuación detrás de las líneas
          },
          {
            label: 'Goles',
            data: goles,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent', // No rellena las barras de goles
            borderColor: '#25D983', // Color de la línea de goles
            borderWidth: 2, // Grosor de la línea de goles
            type: 'line', // Mostrar los goles como una línea
            fill: false, // No llenar el área bajo la línea de goles
            order: -2, // Coloca las líneas de goles delante de las barras de puntuación
            pointRadius:0
          },
          {
            label: 'Asistencias',
            data: asistencias,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent', // No rellena las barras de asistencias
            borderColor: '#FF922D', // Color de la línea de asistencias
            borderWidth: 2, // Grosor de la línea de asistencias
            type: 'line', // Mostrar las asistencias como una línea
            fill: false, // No llenar el área bajo la línea de asistencias
            order: -3, // Coloca las líneas de asistencias delante de las barras de puntuación
            pointRadius: 0
          },
        ],
      },
      options:{

        animation: {
            duration: 1,
            onComplete: function () {

                var chartInstance = this.chart,
                ctx = chartInstance.ctx;

                ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
                ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';
                ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
                var ultimo = [0, 0, 0, 0];
                this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                    if(i==0){
                        var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
                        meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
                            var data = Math.round(dataset.data[index]-0.1);
                            ultimo[index] = data;                        
                            ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 5);
                            
                        });
                        
                    }
                    if(i==1){
                        var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
                        meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
                            var data = dataset.data[index];
                            if(data!=ultimo[index]){
                                ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 5);
                            }                      
                        });
                    }
                    if(i==2){
                        var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
                        meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
                            var data = parseInt(dataset.data[index]*2);
                            if(data!=0){
                                ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 5);
                            }                          
                        });
                    }
                    
                });
            }
          }
      },
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: const ctx = chartInstance.ctx;

Comment: The (first) error you get is from the fact that `chartInstance` is not accessible through `this`, but through the `onComplete` handler's first argument.  Then there are several issues that stem from using code for some old version of chart.js for accessing default font settings and metasets. If you're using the latest version 4, [this](https://jsfiddle.net/grwphces/) is a possible translation. And you should consider using the [`chartjs-datalabels-plugin`](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/) instead of custom-coding the datalabels.